# Can I deploy an application using OpenLDAP on Linux server to Windows client?

Tags: linux, windows, ldap, windows-installer, openldap

Is it possible to deploy installers (for example Chrome browser .exe file) to install on Windows client computers across all office buildings using OpenLDAP? The OpenLDAP is installed on CentOS 8. If it is not possible can Active Directory Help Me?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a directory service to store binary files? This might be possible but it's a terrible idea.

Active Directory is a broad suite of tools. AD Domain Services is basically the OpenLDAP equivalent https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/699.active-directory-domain-services-ad-ds-overview.aspx and doesn't do what you want

AD GP (Group Policy) allows you to push software https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/use-group-policy-to-install-software but if you're only using it to push a Chrome installer, it's overkill to set it all up. It does work though!

You can also use SCCM (oh I guess it's called MECM now, haven't touched it in a hot minute).